# How to replace string dynamically?

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this

```
{columns}
{col}
  Column 1
{/col}

{col}
   Column 2
{/col}
{/columns}

...    

{columns}
{col}
  Column 1
{/col}

{col}
  Column 2
{/col}
{col}
  Column 3
{/col}
{/columns}

// Result
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6">
   ...
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
   ...
 </div>
</div>
...
```

I want replace the `{col}` with `<div class="col-md-x></div>"`. It should be **dynamical**, that's mean if a columns has three cols, the class should be `col-md-4`. The length of col is 12. I'm trying with `preg_replace` or `preg_replace_all`, but it doesn't work really. 
I can only replace the `{columns}` with

```
preg_replace("/{columns}(.+?){\/columns}/is", "<div class='row'>$1</div>", $text);
```

but the other stuff is to difficult. Can someone help me, thx in advance

here is an example
https://3v4l.org/mPrMS

Comment: Fairly easy, very similar regex except that you don't replace, you get the matches, count how many there are (x) then replace with the appropriate

Comment: Really `preg_replace_all`? Not `preg_replace_callback`?

Comment: This takes 2 regexes to accomplish this. `preg_replace_callback('~(?s){columns}(.*?){/columns}~', callback1);` Then in the callback, another callback `preg_replace_callback('~(?s){col}(.*?){/col}~', callback2);` The last callback increments the counter and returns. The first callback  then takes the counter and makes the div.

Comment: You could do it within 1 callback if it's a simple `col` counting thing..

Comment: here my example: https://3v4l.org/mPrMS .It does'nt work really :(

Comment: @test123456 your example works, it's your count calc that's failing. I'll post the fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, your code is working, just don't count string occurrences with preg_match.

```
define("GRID", 12);
function rep($txt) {
    $txt = $txt[1];
    $i = substr_count($txt, '{col}');
    $col = $i > 1 && $i <= GRID ? floor(GRID/$i) : GRID;
    $txt = preg_replace('/{col}(.*?){\/col}/is', '<div class="col-md-'.$col.'">$1</div>', $txt);
    return '<div class="row">'.$txt.'</div>';
}
$input = '{columns} {col} Column 1 {/col} {col} Column 2 {/col} {/columns} {columns} {col}Column 1{/col} {col}Column 2 {/col} {col} Column 3 {/col} {/columns}';
$str = preg_replace_callback('/{columns}(.*?){\/columns}/is', 'rep', $input);
echo $str;
```

That's your code fixed, as you can see here: https://3v4l.org/M5E05

Comment: Thanks, i replace `$i = count($m)` with your `$i = substr_count($text, '{col}');` and now works, thx very much :)))))